# Running into an SQL Error with an MVC Application deployed on IIS

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, iis

So I am new to working on web projects in general. I am working on an MVC application in Visual Studio 2008. I have generated an SQL database within VS, and I have deployed my application on IIS. However when I try to do anything in the application which will spark an SQL query, I get the following error:

"Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to failure in retrieving the user's local application data path. Please make sure the user has a local user profile on the computer. The connection will be closed."

I have hit google on this problem, and people have suggested a number of solutions but  I am unsure how many of them are relevant to me doing this when I'm doing this in VS2008,. I have tried a few simple things suggested like setting the trust level to full, and setting the  Load User Profile to true in IIS, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What edition of SQL are you running where you deployed the application to? If it is not SQL Express, you will need to remove "User Instance=True" from the connection string.